# Increasing array dimension limit in GNU Clisp on Windows

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, clisp, windows64

I statrted learning commmon lisp using Clisp version 2.49 on windows 10. I downloaded Clisp through [This link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/files/), which the official site links to. It is a 32-bit version, and I could not find a 64-bit version (my system is 64 bit).

Anyway, I tried to create a big array using:

```
(make-array 32000000)
```

But I get the following error:

```
MAKE-ARRAY: dimension 32000000 is not of type `(INTEGER 0
  (,ARRAY-DIMENSION-LIMIT))
```

When I print `ARRAY-DIMENSION-LIMIT`, I get 16777215.
I tried changing the limit by running `(defconstant ARRAY-DIMENSION-LIMIT 100000000)`, but it seems to only change it in a local context and not effect the actual limit, as I still get the error.

So I looked at the [implementation notes](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes.html), where it says under

> 15.1. Array Elements

that the dimension limit (and the array total size limit, which seems to be the same) are dependant on the CPU, but even though my CPU is 64-bit so its array dimension limit should be 4294967295, it is the 32-bit limit.

Is there any way around this? A limit of less than 17 million seems pretty low and I find it hard to believe bigger arrays can't be created.
Thank you - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The CLISP you used is pretty old. I haven't seen a newer release. Best to use something lisp SBCL. SBCL has monthly updates.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!